# How to grep for unicode characters?

Tags: python, regex, unicode, grep

How do you search a file using grep for a string of unicode characters?

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences of the string "\xfe\n\xfe". I can find this with Python by doing:

```
open(filename).read().count('\xfe\n\xfe')
```

This finds a few thousand matches.

However, since this loads the entire file into memory, this will crash if I try to search a file larger than my system's memory.

So I'm trying to do the equivalent with grep via:

```
grep -P -c "\xfe\n\xfe" filename
```

It consumes almost 0 memory, which is great, but even though I run this on the same file, it finds 0 matches. What's wrong with my syntax?

Comment: `grep` operates on a line basis.

Comment: You don't have to read the entire file into memory in python. Or, given a sane terminal (well, at least, one that uses the same encoding as your file), you can just paste the characters without escapes. i.e. `grep þ` works.

Comment: I've tested on file with 160000 lines (containing 40000 matches). Python would go much-much faster against grep in this case. @Moses Koledoye's solution should work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to read the entire file into memory. You can iterate on the file and count the occurrence of that string across lines taking a pair of lines at every instant:

```
count = 0
with open(filename) as f:
   prev_line = next(f)
   for line in f:
      if prev_line.endswith('\xfe\n') and line.startswith('\xfe'):
         count += 1
      prev_line = line
```